# Standard workflow to digitize magazines or books using OCR while minimizing file size?

Tags: graphics, pdf, scanner, djvu

To scan books containing just text, black&white images and clear borders, the workflow I've been using is:

- digitize the source using a camera or just a scanner
- use [`scantailor`](http://scantailor.sourceforge.net/)
- finally use [`djvubind`](https://code.google.com/p/djvubind/) to make a small (1-7 MB) djvu-file with ocr background

This works fine. However if you have magazines or books containing lots of colors in the images, structural elements, backgrounds, or images which overlap the margins of the page, using scantailor (in mixed mode) becomes very difficult, and you have to proceed manually with every single page.

So, what would be a good workflow in Linux to digitize such sources and get a small *djvu* or *pdf* file with ocr background?